# Pattern Replacement

Tags: python, regex, pattern-matching

I am a RegEx novice and still coming to terms with pattern matching. But I am trying to understand *pattern replacement*. I am looking to change the currency pattern in the sentence, where the value could be anything and unpredictable, but always in the following format:

```
<currency_symbol><number><number><dot><number><number><letter>
```

For example:

```
'mr x is worth $44.4m and mr y is worth $59.1m'
```

to:

```
'mr x is worth $44400000 and mr y is worth $59100000'
```

I have managed to match the pattern, but not replace:

```
>>> import re
>>> sent = "mr x is worth $44.4m and mr y is worth $59.1m"
>>> print(re.findall(r'\$\d+\.\d+\m', sent))
['$44.4m', '$59.1m']
```

How can I achieve regular expression pattern replacement? Or is there a better way than regex?

Comment: What's wrong with using `re.sub()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to do a substitution like this is using [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) with a function for `repl`:

```
>>> import re
>>> source = 'mr x is worth $44.4m and mr y is worth $59.1m'
>>> def sub_func(match):
    """Convert the match to the new format."""
    string = match.group(0)
    millions = int(float(string[1:-1]) * 1000000)
    return '${:d}'.format(millions)

>>> re.sub(r'\$\d+\.\d+m', sub_func, source)
'mr x is worth $44400000 and mr y is worth $59100000'
```

You can use `'${:,d}'.format(millions)` to get e.g. `'$44,400,000'`.